# jQuery selector - extjs - escape brackets

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS component query selector that looks like this:

```
var field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("myformpanel [fieldName="+fieldName+"][xtype!=container]")[0];
```

this works fine but when `fieldName`has brackets `[ ]`, for example `"Date [From]"` i get this error:

> **Invalid ComponentQuery selector:** "][xtype!=container]"

Comment: One character will solved your issue: \.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add single quotes `'` around the variable to consider the value as a string, like :

```
var field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("myformpanel [fieldName='"+fieldName+"'][xtype!=container]")[0];
```

Hope this helps.